# How do I use Google Translate Javascript widget with Rails Turbolinks?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-translate, turbolinks

Google Translate widget loads fine the first time, but when I navigate to a new page, Turbolinks removes the body and replaces it. This causes the widget to disappear.

```
  %head
    / Google Translate
    :javascript
      function googleTranslateElementInit() { // also called from application.coffee
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,en,es,fr,zh-CN', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
      }
    %script{type: "text/javascript", src: "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"}
```

I tried to call the function upon page load

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  googleTranslateElementInit()
```

But it throws an exception in the browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'InlineLayout' of undefined
    at googleTranslateElementInit (VM145012 dashboard:101)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (application.self-fc93480f6ec8a603a6b9a1d0d9d34ab41a68ef8e4e2a52c661eb84e2b92c170c.js?body=1:7)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:5227)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:4879)
    at Object.t.dispatch (turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1:6)
    at r.t.Controller.r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1:6)
    at r.t.Controller.r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1:6)
    at turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1:6
```

I tried to mark the element permanent

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads

```
%body
  ...
    #google_translate_element{'data-turbolinks-permanent'=>true}
```

But it gave this stack trace when I navigate to a new page and click on it

```
element_main.js:419 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null
    at ou.u.Ke (element_main.js:419)
    at Lh (element_main.js:78)
    at HTMLDivElement.Gh (element_main.js:80)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (element_main.js:76)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this way, but it's very hackey.

`application.coffee`

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('#google_translate_element').empty()
  # googleTranslateElementInit()
```

`application.haml`

```
  %head
    / Google Translate
    :javascript
      function googleTranslateElementInit() { 
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,en,es,fr,zh-CN', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
      }
  %body
    ...
          #google_translate_element
    ...
    = yield
    ...
    %script{type: "text/javascript", src: "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"}
```

Apparently it will not work without being called back from the script tag. You can't call the callback manually and just load the script once. If you don't `.empty()` the tag, then going back in your history will just keep adding more & more Google Translate widgets.